# In CSS @font-face, the font-weight is not to specify what weight to use for this font, but to "match" with the 3 categories of font-weight?

Tags: css, font-face

Let's say we define a `font-family` to use by using `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/oMMgfZMQthOryQo9n22dcuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

It seems that the `font-weight` above is not to specify what weight to present using this font file if the user specifies `font-family: Roboto`, but rather, it is "to match" which font file to use when the `@font-face` specifies the same name.

Example:

If inside of `@font-face`, we specify a `font-weight` of `400`, now the text is presented in Google Chrome (version 48.0, and I can get almost identical results for jsfiddles in this question using the current Firefox 44.0.2), with the light not being able to be lighter, but the bold one is probably made bold by rendering tricks of "double printing" font or "double width" of a pixel:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/

If we make the `font-weight` is made to `900` in `@font-face`, then all 3 lines of text becomes regular:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/1/

So we can see that the `900` is not to specify what to show, using that font file.

So what is the use of `font-weight` inside of `@font-face`?

If we use https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto and link this line:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,300' 
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This will actually load some CSS definitions as a file into the browser:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/oMMgfZMQthOryQo9n22dcuvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('Roboto Black'), local('Roboto-Black'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mnpfi9pxYH-Go5UiibESIpBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
/* other languages omitted here */
```

Now we can see the 3 "weights":

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/5/

but, it is not by closest match by the number -- it looks like it is match by "light", "normal", and "bold" category, because if it is a `301`, it will not match with `299`, even thought it is very close to `299`, but will match with the `400` or `500`:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/6/

The `699` also won't match with `700`, but will match with `400`.

We can also see that, if we reverse the `@font-face`'s `font-weight`, and use `bold`, `normal`, `lighter` for the styles of the text, then `bold` will use the light font file, and `lighter` will use the dark font file:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/10/

However, one strange thing is that, if the `700` is changed in the last `@font-face` to `701`, now all 3 lines will become bold:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/7/

So it is really strange.  It seems the rule is: match with the 3 categories of weights, except the last example.

One more strange thing: if `.section1` is `font-weight: 300`, it show as light:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/8/

but make it `font-weight: 299` -- meaning lighter, now it appears as bold:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vL8m9bj/9/

So making it lighter made it bold.

So what is the rule of `font-weight` inside `@font-face`?

Comment: Make html tag too. :) not only css, css3, font face

Comment: I would be surprised if this was specific to HTML. Do you know something we don't? If so I invite you to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is correct.

The descriptors inside a `@font-face` do not correlate to styling of elements, only to font matching. From the [CSS Fonts Module Level 3 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-prop-desc):

> [4.1] The `@font-face` rule allows for linking to fonts that are
>   automatically fetched and activated when needed. This allows authors
>   to select a font that closely matches the design goals for a given
>   page rather than limiting the font choice to a set of fonts available
>   on a given platform. A set of font descriptors define the location of
>   a font resource, either locally or externally, along with the style
>   characteristics of an individual face.
>
> ...
>
> Each `@font-face` rule specifies a value for every font descriptor, either implicitly or explicitly. Those not given explicit values in the rule take the initial value listed with each descriptor in this specification. These descriptors apply solely within the context of the `@font-face` rule in which they are defined, and do not apply to document language elements. There is no notion of which elements the descriptors apply to or whether the values are inherited by child elements.

Then later under section 4.4:

> [`font-style`, `font-weight` and `font-stretch`] define the
>   characteristics of a font face and are used in the process of matching
>   styles to specific faces. For a font family defined with several
>   @font-face rules, user agents can either download all faces in the
>   family or use these descriptors to selectively download font faces
>   that match actual styles used in document. The values for these
>   descriptors are the same as those for the corresponding font
>   properties except that relative keywords are not allowed, ‘bolder’ and
>   ‘lighter’. If these descriptors are omitted, initial values are
>   assumed.
>
> ...

The advantage of this is that one does not need `font-family` names for "RobotoBold", "RobotoLight", etc.

Comment: you mentioned 'The advantage of this is that one does not need font-family names for "RobotoBold", "RobotoLight"'  but I thought font was traditionally mentioned as font-family and weight separately... but I suppose for light weight font, it might not be that possible if the font itself is not lightweight to begin with, so we need a different font file in some cases

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/ is "this version" as of Jan 2016, while that document says the "latest version" is https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/ and is as of Oct 2013.  So I think it doesn't count itself as a version to qualify as a latest version?  it is a little weird

Comment: @太極者無極而生 The "latest version" means the "latest stable version". The spec in drafts.csswg.org is just an editor's draft.

Answer (score 1):

I was also intrigued by how the @font-face was being selected based on the style's `font-weight` but this MDN article explained it very clearly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#fallback_weights

I was also testing it myself with

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Averta', sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Averta';
  src: url('../public/fonts/averta-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Averta';
  src: url('../public/fonts/averta-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

and proved that

```html
<div style={{ fontWeight: 501 }}>Balance:</div>
```

will display the bold font

while

```html
<div style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>Balance:</div>
```

will display the regular font